# Lenovo ThinkPad T420s hotkey driver is missing on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad, hotkeys

I'm using an old Lenovo ThinkPad T420s. I installed a fresh Windows 10 OS on my device. Previously I was using Windows 7. All the drivers worked perfectly on Windows 7. After installing Windows 10, I'm having a problem. There are no official Lenovo <kbd>Fn</kbd> key (hotkey) drivers for Windows 10 for my ThinkPad T420s.

Is there any hotkey driver available for Lenovo ThinkPad T420s for Windows 10?

Comment: See if the windows 8 driver will work....https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/migr-74261

Answer (score 0):

try this Hotkey Features Integration for Windows 8 (32-bit, 64-bit), 7 (32-bit, 64-bit), Vista (32-bit, 64-bit), XP and 2000 - ThinkPad from the official Lenovo website
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds014985